# C++ GUI development with graph support

Tags: c++, gui, qt, gnuplot

So, I am developing a project in the RPi where I will be reading values from a sensor using I2C, and this values will be plotted in real time using a GUI. The project is strictly being developed C++ (we are extensively  using C++ libraries ) so no Python is allowed.

I've thoroughly searched for C++ GUI options and come up with the very well known Qt and GTK.

So, Qt. I started developing the GUI on my laptop and everything worked fine, I pulled off the graphs using Qt Charts (which is not in the main installation) and they worked good with simulated sensor values. However, when I moved to the RPi I tried opening the project and of course Qt Charts was missing, I googled a lot but I didn't find a way of installing it on the RPi. I am a bit doubtful if maybe I got over the line and this was just as easy as add the library but I am really doubtful. So also if anyone knows this, please help.

Now, GTK. I downloaded Glade and was getting the hang of how it works and everything, but before going further I decided checking if there were available tools for plotting. I found gnuplot and [whatnot](http://www.gnuplot.info/links.html) libraries interfacing it, gtkgraph (which seems deprecated) and even a [suggestion](https://github.com/liberforce/gtk-samples/tree/master/c/gtk3-graph) of making my own widget using cairo and tbh I am thinking GTK is not the way to go either.

So, for all you community out there do you have any suggestion on how should I proceed ? Maybe another C++ GUI tool? Or another GTK or Qt library suggestion that is known to work with the RPi? I am even thinking of messing up with graphics directly(OpenCV and that) but I am not sure how difficult it might turn out.

Thanks in advance and any advice is welcomed.

Comment: The Pi is really not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you have tried to install Qt Charts, but there's `qml-module-qtcharts` package you can install with `apt-get`. Alternatively, you could build Qt Charts [from source](https://github.com/qt/qtcharts). According to their build instructions, it should be as easy as running

```
qmake CONFIG+=debug
make
sudo make install
```